# Wrong "From" Email Address when Replying & Forwarding in Outlook 2010 & Saves in wrong Sent folder

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, reply

Software - MS Outlook 2010
Also - I use a 3rd party Recruiting CRM application built on MS Framework so highly compatible, with an Outlook Add-in component for capturing emails I receive from anyone in my database and any new person who sends a resume.

Situation - I have a POP3 Account with my ISP and use that for personal email.  I run a home business and use a hosting company for a business email address that forwards email to the personal email address.  Within Outlook Email Account settings - I have two POP3 accounts set up - personal and business hence - two email account folders set up in Outlook.

Per Outlook 2010, when sending a NEW email, the "From" address is correct for whichever account I'm in at the time. This was also true when Replying, Forwarding and the Sent folder until about a week ago.  I had not changed any settings.

The Problem - When replying or forwarding an email from my business account the "From Address" is now the personal email address and these emails are saved in the Personal sent items folder vs. business email folder.

I've been working on this for hours, have checked settings, deleted and re-set up accounts, checked the hosting company set up etc.  When it was working the Default account was set to the personal email account.  So I tried changing the default account to the Bus acc. - to no avail.  Didn't think it would since it had worked previously but had to try.

Has anyone come across this problem?  If so - You'll be my hero and save me a few grey hairs.  Most apps update automatically - at this point I can only guess one of the updates caused this.

Thank you,

Jill from Minneapolis

Comment: Tip. Edit to make it shorter. Please!! Consider stating your question at top. (use formatting, __text__ - _italic_, ` for 'effect', ** **bold**).